# How do I combine these two rewrite rules?

Tags: html, .htaccess

I'm trying to combine these two rewrite rules, I get the error "too many redirects" whatever I do. The goal is to keep the index.php rewriterule and combine it with a force ssl rule.

What I want to combine:

1:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [PT,L]
```

2:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```